# SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0(…)

Tags: javascript, ajax

Using ajax and json format. But it occur these message. In php,     array("message" =>  "Success", "data" => $data) can be shown successfully. But it cannot callback to ajax. How can i fix it. please help me.  I don't want to delete the datatype "json".

```
   success: function(Return)
          {



             if  (Return.message ==='Success') {
                 window.location="Homepage.html";

             }
             else {

                 window.alert("No such account or wrong password");
             }
         },
         error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
             console.log(xhr.statusText);
             console.log(textStatus);
             console.log(error);
         }

  $result = $conn->query($sql);
$data = $result->fetch_assoc();

if ($data)
{
    echo json_encode
    (
        array("message" =>  "Success", "data" => $data)
    );


}
else
{
    echo json_encode
    (
        array("message" =>  "Fail")

    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should put some header type :

```
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

use that before the echo json_encode.